# Specify alg when verifying JWT token

Tags: jwt

In `jsonwebtoken 8.5.1`, the token can be verify as for HS256 as example:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const decoded = await jwt.verify(jwt_token, jwtPrivateKey, {ignoreExpiration: true});
```

Since `alg:none` is a known vulnerability, is there a way to force expected `alg` used when verifying? Also does it enhance the security by specifying `alg` in verifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the algorithm you expect with the `algorithms` key, see the [documentation of `jwt.verify()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback):

> `algorithms`: List of strings with the names of the allowed algorithms. For instance, `["HS256", "HS384"]`.